# Uninstall xcode but keep other dependencies

Tags: xcode, macos

I do not work on iOS or OSX apps, but I do a fair amount of other development. Therefore, I need to keep things like python, gcc, etc. How can I uninstall the xcode app without removing these other things?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***How can I uninstall the xcode app without removing these other things?***

First point to note is that python comes pre-installed on your mac and can be interacted with independently of Xcode.

1. You delete the Xcode application from your applications folder (`/Applications`) and leave the developer tools in place. This would leave the command line tools in place, you could call this a bit of a hack.

location of command line tools:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/
```

2. Completely remove Xcode and command line tools and use a package manager tool like [HomeBrew](http://brew.sh) to install the tools you require.

Comment: Of course Homebrew requires the command line tools to operate, so option 2 will put you into an unpleasant situation.

Comment: Does dragging Xcode to trash work? I recall that one time when I did that it seemed to remove the command line tools as well.